# Bootstrap ratio

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to build a card styled layout. The cards should have the aspect ratio of a standard tcg card.

So with an aspect service, I have found that I have to add

```
padding-top: 39.68%;
```

In the plunkr, I have built this.  It works fine on the initial state of col-sm-3, but as soon as I switch to col-xs-2, the aspect ratio is completely different.

If you resize it in plunkr, you will see what I mean.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/znbQymDSPmn6BK28l1mZ?p=preview)

Comment: have you tried using a media query to change the padding value?

Comment: @kai this should be done with col-xs and col-sm it swaps the css code also

Comment: Eventually I miss understanding something, the padding should keep the ratio between height and width. As simple example, the height should be every time twice as height as the width.

Comment: What is your current required aspect ratio

Comment: 56-57 mm x 81-82 mm  this ratio I want to keep

Comment: Is this what you're going for? https://plnkr.co/edit/pCUGaEUDN6sBrsLBtswB?p=preview

Comment: @MichaelCoker this seems to work, dont understand the difference to mine, except the 139% instead of 39% but yeah it keeps the ratio.

Comment: You shouldn't apply the padding directly to an element that has a specified `width` - the width needs to be `auto` for the padding to work. And the size of a tcg card is 63 x 88 mm. 88 / 63 = 139. That's how you calculate the ratio. So I'm applying that padding to a pseudo element and that will control the height of the card it's applied to. Want me to submit that as an answer?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes pls thank you, now I have 2 working solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't apply the padding directly to an element that has a specified width - the width needs to be `auto` for the padding to work and represent the aspect ratio of a tcg card.

The size of a tcg card is 63 x 88 mm. To get the height as a percentage, divide the height by the width - 88 / 63 = 139%.

Since you don't want to apply it to the card itself, apply that padding to a pseudo element and that will control the height of the card it's applied to.

```css
/* Styles go here */
.card {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 3px solid;
}
.card:before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 139.68253968%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 card col-xs-3">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 card col-xs-3">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 card col-xs-3">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 card col-xs-3">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 card col-xs-3">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 card col-xs-3">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 card col-xs-3">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2  card col-xs-3">
          2
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the aspect ratio you have provided i.e, 56:81 card height should be `81/56*width`. card width is varying according to the bootstrap classes `col-xs-3`(16.666667%) and `col-sm-2`(25%).

We can maintain above mentioned height by giving it as padding to the div. Now if we add any content to the div then the height of the div incereses, to avoid this add a wrapper to your div.

Padding percentages are `24.1%` i.e 81/56*16.66667% for `sm` and `36.16%` i.e, 81/56 *25% for `xs`

```css
.card-wrapper {
    padding-top: 24.1%;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 3px solid;
    position: relative;
}

.card-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .card-wrapper {
    padding-top: 36.16%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 card-wrapper col-xs-3">
          <div class="card-content">
            1        
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 card-wrapper col-xs-3">
          <div class="card-content">
            2        
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 card-wrapper col-xs-3">
          <div class="card-content">
            1        
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2  card-wrapper col-xs-3">
          <div class="card-content">
            2        
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 card-wrapper col-xs-3">
          <div class="card-content">
            1        
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 card-wrapper col-xs-3">
          <div class="card-content">
            2        
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 card-wrapper col-xs-3">
          <div class="card-content">
            1        
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2  card-wrapper col-xs-3">
          <div class="card-content">
            2        
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works, quite not sure why. I touht I can somehow define the ratio an keep it. Like 4:3 no matter what with is coming. But ty.